# Как получить элементы массива после последней цифры 6?

Tags: java, массивы

Есть массив, из которого нужно вытащить значения после последней 6.

Пример массива:

```
[1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 9, 8, 6, 0, 1, 3]
```

На выходе должно быть:

```
[0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: В чем сложность? Что у Вас не получается?

Comment: Не могу понять как найти индекс последней шестерки. Понимаю, что это должно быть элементарно, но сообразить не могу.

Comment: @nvfredy а если с конца массив перебирать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ без собственного перебора:

```
    public class ArrayTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Integer[] a = {1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 9, 8, 6, 0, 1, 3};
            List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(a);
            int i = integers.lastIndexOf(6);
            List<Integer> result = integers.subList(i + 1, integers.size());
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result.toArray()));
        }
    }
```

Если же самому реализовывать, то перебор с конца и получение значений после первого найденного значения.

Comment: точно, благодарю

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] arr = {1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 9, 8, 6, 0, 1, 3};

// искомое число
int required = 6;

// ищем индекс последнего вхождения искомого числа
int last = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        .filter(i -> arr[i] == required)
        .max().getAsInt();

// получаем числа из массива после искомого числа
int[] arr2 = IntStream.range(last, arr.length)
        .skip(1)
        .map(i -> arr[i])
        .toArray();

// выводим результат
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
int[] arr = {1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3, 9, 8, 6, 0, 1, 3};

// искомое число
int required = 6;

// получаем числа из массива
// после искомого числа
// в обратном порядке
int[] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
        // обходим индексы массива
        // в обратную сторону
        .map(i -> arr.length - 1 - i)
        // элменты массива
        .map(i -> arr[i])
        // пока не встретили искомый элемент
        .takeWhile(i -> i != required)
        // выгружаем в массив
        .toArray();

// разворачиваем массив
int[] arr3 = IntStream.range(0, arr2.length)
        // обходим индексы массива
        // в обратную сторону
        .map(i -> arr2.length - 1 - i)
        // элменты массива
        .map(i -> arr2[i])
        // выгружаем в массив
        .toArray();

// выводим результат
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr3)); // [0, 1, 3]
```